# adobe air apk won't run on android 4.4.2

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a android 4.1.2 device and my adobe air as3 apk runs on it. I also have a 4.4.2 device, and the apk doesn't run on that one. I am having a tough time finding out what's wrong, though. Has anyone found this problem too? I would love ddms output, like I am used to from eclipse, but I don't know how to start.

I've googled a little, but the problem seems to be mine alone. I am using Flash CS6 on a windows install as my development environment. Also, the AIR version on CS6 is 3.4.

Any help would be appreciated. I am using a captive runtime.

Comment: Could you try upgrading to a more recent version of AIR? 3.4 is nearly 2 years old. We're now on 13.0 (jumped from 4.0->13.0 as part of a version numbering switch). Make sure to back up your previous SDK first before upgrading, just to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the old AIR version. Here's a link saying that the 'new' 3.9 now supports KitKat (Android 4.4.2): http://news.softpedia.com/news/Adobe-Air-with-Android-4-4-KitKat-Support-Out-Now-on-Google-Play-417056.shtml

Try updating your SDK AND your AIR on the phone.

Comment: Softpedia sensationalizes manufacturer release notes. AIR 3.9 verified full support for Android 4.4, but it did not add it. If I remember correctly from the bug tracker, there were a few minor issues relating to the camera and the new options allowing apps to overlay a transparent menu, but that was it. Nothing that would cause the app to not launch on 4.4. Additionally, I am able to launch an app I have in the Play Store that was built with 3.7. While I agree he should update, I wouldn't say that is the only issue here.

Comment: He's building with 3.4, which is so old, that I'm almost sure it cannot run on KitKat. Anyways, I haven't tried it, but I guess as they have release notes for adding support in later versions, this should mean that old ones won't run properly. I agree there might be other issues, but I cannot think of any now :)

Comment: For the record, I just downloaded another app I created (one I try to forget I did...) that was built using AIR 3.1 and it works just fine on Android 4.4. I definitely do not believe that is the issue here, unless they are trying to use a feature not added until later versions (which they would be warned of, if they are even able to compile)

Comment: for whatever reason, updating the air sdk worked. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

here is the link to download latest air version

http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html

-open flash > help > manage air sdk > you can remove add new air here